# Using ionic to make an app for Androids and iPhones

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4

I've just finished building my website and will deploy it shortly, however I want to make an app and I was hoping to find a way of taking my existing front end code and dump it into ionic and get a nice app out of it.

Is it going to be that simple to make an app using ionic or will I have to rebuild the front end all over again if I'm going to use ionic?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you made your site with. If you used a framework compatible with ionic like angular it is fine (see this article: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/converting-angular-web-application-into-ionic-app-5af678325626)

If you have developed in pure Html / css / js you can always reuse part of your code but you will need to import it in a framework (React, Vue or Angular)